# How can I take a matrix inverse with ndarray without using BLAS backend in Rust?

Tags: rust

I need to take an inverse of a matrix to fit a linear regression to my data in Rust. I've tried using [ndarray](https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray) for that but have not found a good way to do it without using BLAS backend. Any suggestions how can I find matrix inverse in Rust without using BLAS backend?

Comment: You can code [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix) if you can't use BLAS. Or try [LAPACK](https://docs.rs/lapack/0.16.0/lapack/fn.dgetrf.html)

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to avoid implementing gaussian elimination myself but this is always a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you'll need BLAS/LAPACK backend to find matrix inverse with ndarray. I suggest to look at [nalgebra](https://nalgebra.org/) if you want to take matrix inverse and decompose matrices in pure Rust.

I have a blog post where I share some code that takes inverse of a matrix with nalgebra: https://vlad-orlov.com/regressor-in-rust/

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never :)

```
    let weights = [
        [0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0],
        [0.5, -0.91, 0.26, -0.5],
        [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87],
    ];

    let rows = weights.len();
    let cols = weights[0].len(); // Might want to error check by testing all rows.
    let mut weights_t = vec![vec![0.0; rows]; cols];
    for c in 0..cols {
        for r in 0..rows {
            weights_t[c][r] = weights[r][c];
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).